# Perform different field validation for the same model from 2 different controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to generate a quick registration form to use Facebook, Twitter and Linked sign in on my app. But I do have user model that validates some fields on the previous sign up procedure.

I am trying to extend the Registration controller, based on Devise, in order to use the same database for quick registration from the external sign in. This question is formulated because I am running a trial and then I have the sign up form asking for the credit card.

I have this controller:

```
class Users::QuickRegistrationController < Users::RegistrationsController

  self.model_class = Users::RegistrationsController

end
```

And then I have this user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  validates :name, :presence => true
  validates :first_surname, :presence => true
  validates :prefered_language, :presence => true
  validates :dni, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true #, :format => {:with => /(^\d{7,8}[a-zA-Z]$)|(^[a-zA-Z]\d{7}[a-zA-Z]$)/, :unless => "dni.blank?"}
  validates :phone_number, :presence => true, :format => { :with => /^((\d{9})|([+]\d{11}))$/, :unless => "phone_number.blank?"}, :uniqueness => true
  validates :birthdate, :presence => true, :age => {:adult => :over}
  validates :legal_conditions, :acceptance => {:accept => true}
  validates :email, :confirmation => true
  validates :email_confirmation, :presence => true
  validates :password_confirmation, :presence => true, :if => "new_record?"
  validates :country, :presence => true
```

Can I say something like validates :first_surname, :presence => false for the Users::QuickRegistrationController and :first_surname, :presence => true for Users::RegistrationsController?

Additionally, there's a solution to solve this issue on Ruby, can you provide any tutorial or related link?

Comment: Validations are always based on the model, not on the controller. Why would you do that? Are you getting different data from Facebook, than you require by your default register process?

Comment: I wait to run a trial and I only need an email and a password from the user. When the trial finishes I run the normal sign up to subscribe the user to the service. Then I need more validations on more fields

Comment: that looks wrong. how about hermetization? can't you keep absolutely necessary details in User class, like password and e-mail, and the rest in UserDetails ? If your details depend on method you signed up, you might want to create separate classes for each of them, like FacebookDetails extends UserDetails etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As 23tux says, validations are based on the model. What I'd do is add a new column to your model:

```
add_column :products, :quick_registration, :boolean, default => true
```

Then in your User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  validates :name, :presence => true
  validates :email, :confirmation => true
  validates :email_confirmation, :presence => true


  with_options :unless => :quick_registration? do |u|

    # These only validate during full registration
    u.validates :first_surname, :presence => true
    u.validates :prefered_language, :presence => true
    u.validates :dni, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true #, :format => {:with => /(^\d{7,8}[a-zA-Z]$)|(^[a-zA-Z]\d{7}[a-zA-Z]$)/, :unless => "dni.blank?"}
    u.validates :phone_number, :presence => true, :format => { :with => /^((\d{9})|([+]\d{11}))$/, :unless => "phone_number.blank?"}, :uniqueness => true
    u.validates :birthdate, :presence => true, :age => {:adult => :over}
    u.validates :legal_conditions, :acceptance => {:accept => true}
    u.validates :password_confirmation, :presence => true, :if => "new_record?"
    u.validates :country, :presence => true

  end
end
```

Then in your controller, you can 'switch on' the additional validations by setting `quick_registration` to false:

```
@user.quick_registration = false
@user.save   # all validations should fire
```